# variadic template in nested class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm experimenting with variadic template and got a strange problem, where I don't really understand why the error message is raised.

```cpp
template<int v0, int ...Vs>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename nested = void,
        typename = void>
    class Reduce
    {
    public:
        static int const value = v0;
    };

    template<typename nested>
    class Reduce<nested,
        typename std::enable_if<0<sizeof...(Vs)>::type>
    {
    public:
        static int const value = v0 + Foo<Vs...>::template Reduce<>::value;
    };
};
```

This Code brings the error message

```
//example code
int s = Foo<0,1,2,3,4,5>::Reduce<>::value;
std::cout << s << std::endl;

error: incomplete type 'F<5>::Reduce<>' used in nested name specifier
```

I inserted the nested dummy template parameter because nested template classes in a template class can't be fully specialized. Actually I don't understand why the compiler complains about an incomplete type.
When I change the variadic stuff to

```cpp
template<int v0, int ...Vs>
class Reduced
{
public:
    static int const value = v0 + Reduce<Vs...>::value;
};

template<int v0>
class Reduced<v0>
{
public:
    static int const value = v0;
};

template<int v0, int ...Vs>
class Foo
{
public:
    class Reduce
    {
    public:
        static int const value = Reduced<v0, Vs...>::value;
    };
};
```

it work's, but I don't know why the other one does not. Any idea why the compiler is throwing that error? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is attributed to the quote of the C++ standard *§14.7.3/p16 Explicit specialization [temp.expl.spec]* (emphasis mine):

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class
>   template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the
>   member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain
>   unspecialized, **except that the declaration shall not explicitly
>   specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates
>   are not explicitly specialized as well.**

That is, you can't have objects of specialized type `Foo<int...>::Reduced<>` unless `Foo` the enclosing class is specialized as well.

You could amend this in the following way:

```
template<int v0, int ...Vs>
class Foo {
public:
  class Reduce {
  public:
    static int const value = v0 + Foo<Vs...>::Reduce::value;
  };
};

template<int v0>
class Foo<v0> {
public:
  class Reduce {
  public:
    static int const value = v0;
  };
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4d8aec0484d4942)

Or you could get rid of nested classes:

```
template<int v0, int ...Vs>
class Foo {
public:
  static int const value = v0 + Foo<Vs...>::value;
};

template<int v0>
class Foo<v0> {
public:
  static int const value = v0;
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c3cf7f4e82dfc60)

C++17 introduces fold expressions. With folds expressions you could do what you want only by doing:

```
template<int v0, int ...Vs>
class Foo {
public:
  static const int s = v0 + (Vs + ...);
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33fb71fc241bb4e5)

Comment: With that approach I don't need the template argument 'nested' at all, right?
Furthermore I like to avoid a specialization of the Foo class. Because in the real use case it contains a lot more other stuff I don't want to reimplement for the specialization.

Comment: @Feuerteufel Yes, template argument is superfluous with this approach.

Comment: @Feuerteufel I've added an edit check if it suits you.

Comment: I have to stick to C++11 for the moment, but good to know that there will be unfolding with an operator, that's really nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
typename std::enable_if<0<sizeof...(Vs)>::type
```

You need to wrap the inequality check in parens.

```
typename std::enable_if< (0 < sizeof...(Vs)) >::type
```

Comment: Nope, that does not solve the problem. I would be surprised, if the parser can not distinguish between < as a bracket and operator.